# KDE 4.5: Focus on scroll

Tags: kde, kde-4, focus, scrolling

With KDE 3.5 windows always got focus as soon as I scrolled over them but with KDE 4.x this doesn't seem to be possible.

At the `Focus` settings I only see the policies "Click to focus", "Focus Follows Mouse", "Focus Under Mouse" and "Focus Strictly Under Mouse". But none of them seem to do what I want.

The behaviour I'm looking for:

- Focus does *not* follow the mouse with simple hovering a window
- Screens get focused by either clicking or scrolling
- Scrolling on a screen should only focus it. Not raise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Settings > Window Behaviour > Window Behaviour > Window Actions (tab) > Wheel (dropdown)

change from 'Scroll' to 'Activate & Scroll'

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.